# How can I remotely execute a script in Windows?

Tags: windows, administration

I would like to have a Windows 2003 server fire a script to fire another script in a separate Windows Server 2008 computer.

I have been told that Powershell can do that, and that's fine, but I need more specific details.

Does anyone have any tips for this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably better suited for serverfault.com. I have marked to close for this reason; stackoverflow now supports moving questions between sites.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from SysInternals

Comment: This seems like the best answer.  I'll try it at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

Look into the syntax for the AT command. You can use it to schedule a process to run on a remote machine.

The AT command schedules commands and programs to run on a computer at
a specified time and date. The Schedule service must be running to use
the AT command.

```
AT [\\computername] [ [id] [/DELETE] | /DELETE [/YES]]
AT [\\computername] time [/INTERACTIVE]
    [ /EVERY:date[,...] | /NEXT:date[,...]] "command"

\\computername     Specifies a remote computer. Commands are scheduled on the
                   local computer if this parameter is omitted.
id                 Is an identification number assigned to a scheduled
                   command.
/delete            Cancels a scheduled command. If id is omitted, all the
                   scheduled commands on the computer are canceled.
/yes               Used with cancel all jobs command when no further
                   confirmation is desired.
time               Specifies the time when command is to run.
/interactive       Allows the job to interact with the desktop of the user
                   who is logged on at the time the job runs.
/every:date[,...]  Runs the command on each specified day(s) of the week or
                   month. If date is omitted, the current day of the month
                   is assumed.
/next:date[,...]   Runs the specified command on the next occurrence of the
                   day (for example, next Thursday).  If date is omitted, the
                   current day of the month is assumed.
"command"          Is the Windows NT command, or batch program to be run.
```

Answer (score 4):

easiest way that is use will be in two steps

a.   installing cygwin to remote pc

b. run ssh hudson@mcs '/cygdrive/c/path_to_script.bat'

Answer (score 2):

Speaking about `PsExec`, I would **strongly** suggest to use Cygwin/OpenSSH instead.

SSH has multiple advantages (over tools like `PsExec` or even custom-made services).
For example, try to use with `PsExec` and implement what these `bash` / `ssh` command lines do:

```
ssh user@remotehost "find . -name something" 2> all.errors.txt
ssh user@remotehost "grep -r something ."
if [ "$?" == "0" ]
then
    echo "FOUND"
else
    echo "NOT FOUND"
fi
```

Good Luck!

- SSH transfers (!) remote stdout / stderr / exit status to *local* shell for inspection
  (killer feature and common requirement to integrate remote execution into logic of local scripts)
- Cygwin/OpenSSH provides *standard* POSIX shell environment 
  (efficient time investment, fundamental tools, cross-platform ready, compatible habits, etc.)
- You can still/always run *all native* Windows application 
  (including automatic execution of `*.bat` files by `cmd` processor)
- You can configure password-less auth using public keys 
  (think about unattended automated tasks)

---

**Tip**

There was one requirement I had problems with initially: 
background `sshd` service had to execute apps in user's graphical session 
(to make application window appear in desktop environment).

The [acceptable solution](http://spectlog.com/content/Run_cygwin_sshd_in_user_seesion_to_start_GUI_application) for me was running `sshd` service *directly* in user's GUI session 
(start automatically when user logs in, follow the link to see configuration file changes):

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -f /home/user/sshd_config
```

Comment: I am actually using SSH, fwiw.  The problem is SSH can't start a gui program (even though said gui program has no gui...)

Comment: @Frew, the [link](http://spectlog.com/content/Run_cygwin_sshd_in_user_seesion_to_start_GUI_application) from the tip specifically addresses running GUI applications remotely on Windows. And in my opinion, there is no simpler and more *harmonic* solution to this problem (at least in the context I had to deal with it). If the Windows host in question exists for a pure server role, you may still need to automatically login this user after each reboot (so that the desktop session and `sshd` remain active all the time).

Comment: I may look into it again, but I had pretty major issues with the project that this was for (automated testing of an NSIS installer) to the point that I had to give up entirely.

Comment: @Frew, in fact, I also needed remote GUI execution for (client side) automated testing.

Comment: Well, when I move to creating the installer (and not just the updater) of this thing I'll reconsider :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution from http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Q_22959948.html is:

> What I provide was a script that takes
>   parameters... In this case it takes 4.
>   1) Server: if you pass -server it will
>   only do that one server 2) List: You
>   can provide a list file of servers. 
>   3) Service: Name of the service you
>   want to modify  4) Verbose: is not
>   used here.
>
> I did have some mistakes that I
>   changed in the following code. To use
>   cut/paste the code into a file called
>   Set-RemoteService.ps1. Make sure to
>   set your executionpolicy to run
>   scripts... it will not by default. You
>   do that by using the
>   set-executionpolicy cmdlet. PS>
>   Set-Executionpolicy "RemoteSigned" to
>   run the script you do  PS>
>   C:\PathToScript\Set-RemoteService.ps1
>   -list c:\ServerList.txt -service "DHCP"
>
> ######################### Param($server,$list,$service,[switch]$verbose)
>
> if($Verbose){$VerbosePreference =
>   "Continue"} if($list) {
>       foreach($srv in (get-content $list))
>       {
>           $query = "Select * from Win32_Service where Name='$service'"
>           $myService = get-WmiObject -query $query -computer $srv
>           $myService.ChangeStartMode("Automatic")
>           $myService.Start()
>       } } if($server) {
>       $query = "Select * from Win32_Service where Name='$service'"
>       $myService = get-WmiObject -query $query -computer $server
>       $myService.ChangeStartMode("Automatic")
>       $myService.Start() }

Comment: This script starts existing Services on a remote computer, but doesn't run arbitrary scripts.