# Running Jmeter remotely from command line

Tags: testing, jmeter

Is it possible to run Jmeter on remote server without having Jmeter client on local machine.
I mean can I just run jmeter.bat on remote machine from command prompt, so that it just run tests on remote server and store results in listener.jtl file over there, without any jmeter client on my machine.

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote machine?

Comment: its on private network. Jmeter should run on server and tester should be able to run it from cmd line

Comment: I don't plan to stress test webserver, so I'm not looking for distributed testing. I just wan't to install JMeter on 1 machine and let every tester to run it from their machine from command line.

Comment: If the remote machine is Linux, you may run JMeter like this `ssh jmeter.sh ...`

Comment: Its windows, is there a way ?

Comment: sorry, problem was quite simple. psExec can be used to run Jmeter remotely. So question is not related to jmeter but executing batch/exe files remotely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the link: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html.
Just go through the documentation available in the Jmeter's website.

The scenario given by you is some sort of "distributed testing" itself, where you want every tester to execute load testing from the machine where JMeter is installed.

For this purpose you must copy JMeter in each testers machine and make the entry of your JMeter server machine (Host Machine).

Now when every tester will run JMeter they will be able to run the load on the JMeter Host Machine.

```
jmeter -n -t script.jmx -l listener.jtl -R HostMachineIP
```

Comment: That is precisely the problem, I don't want to copy JMeter on tester's machine. My intention is not to stress test either but to perform functional test using Jmeter. There will be one remote machine (server) with JMeter that will test a webserver. Each tester will just invoke jmeter.bat on remote machine, that run JMeter on remote machine and save the result over there. I can use PsExec, batchfile and maybe python to execute process on remote machine.

Comment: Looks like there is a bunch of solutions that allow you to run .bat with params remotely on win-machine, from both nix-and win-clients: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095807/run-a-windows-xp-bat-script-remotely-from-a-ubuntu-machine), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861148/how-can-i-remotely-execute-a-script-in-windows), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786185/run-powershell-scripts-on-remote-pc), [4](http://serverfault.com/questions/108397/is-it-possible-to-run-a-batch-script-remotely-on-a-windows-machine-from-linux-wi). That's not scope of jmeter's functionality.

Comment: Ok... in that case if you'r able to run the jmeter.bat of your JMeter host machine from Tester's machine... probably the command here will work for you. <your command to execute the .bat file from JMeter Host M/C> -n -t \\<JMeterHostIP>\script.jmx -l \\<JMeterHostIP>\ListenerName.jtl

Comment: `code`<your command to execute the .bat file from JMeter Host M/C>\apache-jmeter-2.6\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t \\<JMeterHostIP>\script.jmx -l \\<JMeterHostIP>\ListenerName.jtl