# How to execute .exe file found on remote windows using OS Process Sampler in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to the Jmeter and I need to run an executable file that exists on a remote windows machine, I used OS sampler request but I don't know how to make it connect to the remote machine

Comment: Welcome to the Site! Please provide more details on how you tried to approach the issue. In particular post any relevant code that yo have attempted to use and where/how you were not unable to proceed. Note that there may already be information out there to help you get started like this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606680/running-jmeter-remotely-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Using [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) like:

   - Command: `cmd.exe'
   - First argument: `/c`
   - Second argument: `/path/to/psexec.exe \your-remote-machine -u username -p password -c /path/to/file.exe
2. Using [Windows Powershell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-6)

   - Command: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
   - First argument: `$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String ${password} -AsPlainText -Force; $credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "${username}",$password; Invoke-Command -Computer ${host} -cred $credentials -scriptBlock { /path/to/file.exe }`

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/)