# Triggering a windows batch script from unix shell script

Tags: unix

I Have a unix shell script, after it runs, it will ftp a file to windows server. Then i need to manuallu schedule a windows batch script. couls you please suggest me method where i can call the batch script from the unix shell script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean, you want to execute the batch script remotely, right? From a unix box?

Comment: Why you tag question with #java?

Comment: If you are sending a Windows Shell script to a Windows server and want it to run on that server, you have to set up a service on that server to do so. You might look at Windows Remote Shell and see if it is appropriate: http://blog.hernanjlarrea.com.ar/index.php/introducing-windows-remote-shell/

Comment: Yes thejh, i want to execute or call the windows batch script from unix box.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16720186/2471910

It talks specifically about invoking a windows program from another windows machine (instead of a unix machine) but the concepts are the same since ssh is available on unix as well.